# Dynamically Updating IMultiSelectOption

Tags: angular

I am using the angular2-dropdown-multiselect npm package and am having trouble. I want to dynamically update the IMultiSelectOption object through an API call so that the dropdown can be updated as the user goes. I can see that the JSON object is being returned from the API correctly, but after I assign it to the IMultiSelectOption object, it says the IMultiSelectOption object is empty. I think the variable has to be a certain type, but I'm not sure what that is.

Initializing the object like this works.

```
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.myOptions = [
    { "id": "type", "name": "Type" },
    { "id": "status", "name": "Status" }
  ]
}
```

But doing this:

```
refreshFields(){
  this.http.get('/fields').subscribe(response => this.fieldObject = 
  response.json());
  this.myOptions = this.fieldObject;
}
```

or this:

```
refreshFields(){
  this.http.get('/fields').subscribe(response => this.myOptions = 
  response.json());
}
```

ruins it. In the first case, myOptions becomes empty https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBI6f.png

In the second case myOptions becomes a single object with no value. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd7Gj.png

My JSON object looks like this.

```
[{"id": "issuetype", "name": "Issue Type"}, {"id": "issuekey", "name": "Key"}, {"id": "status", "name": "Status"}, {"id": "summary", "name": 
"Summary"}, {"id": "created", "name": "Created"}]
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are dealing with Observables, that are actually asynchronous. So, while doing =>

```
refreshFields(){
 this.http.get('/fields').subscribe(response => this.fieldObject = 
 response.json());
 this.myOptions = this.fieldObject;
}
```

`myOptions` gets updated with `fieldObject` first, then `fieldObject` receives value. So, it shows emply list. And, when you did this =>

```
refreshFields(){
 this.http.get('/fields').subscribe(response => this.myOptions = 
 response.json());
}
```

You converted `response` into JSON string. So, `myOptions` reives a single string that doesn't match it's defined type.

Do it like this =>

```
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.myOptions = [
    { "id": "type", "name": "Type" },
    { "id": "status", "name": "Status" }
  ];
}  

refreshFields(){
  this.http.get('/fields').subscribe((response:IMultiSelectOption[]) => {
    let i = 0;
    while(i < response.length)
    {
      this.myOptions.push(response[i]);
      i++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah of course, observables are tricky and I should definitely read more about them. This solution makes sense but when I try it I get this error: Argument of type '(response: IMultiSelectOption[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => void'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Create a stackblitz and share it... Provide mock data instead of your api call.

Comment: Try (response: any)

Answer (score 0):

```
refreshFields(value){
  this.myOptions = [];
  this.optionsModel = [];
  this.http.get(value).subscribe((response: any) => {
    let i = 0;
    let str = response._body.slice(2, -2);
    str = str.replace(/'/gi, "\"");
    let resArray = str.split("|");
    while(i < resArray.length-1)
    {
      this.fieldObject = this.convertToMultiSelect(JSON.parse(resArray[i]));
     this.myOptions.push(this.fieldObject);
      i++;
    }
  });
  return;
}

convertToMultiSelect(items: any[]): IMultiSelectOption[] {
  return items;
}
```

So this is how I ended up solving this using the answer from [@AbhishekJaiswal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9979778/abhishek-jaiswal). I returned the response as a string, parsed it into an array, sent it through a function to change its type to IMultiSelectOptions and then pushed it into the options array. It's probably not the most efficient way of doing this but it works. I think my original problem was that the JSON object was not being returned in the correct format.